# How to read/write a hive table from within the spark executors

Tags: apache-spark, executors

I have a requirement wherein I am using DStream to retrieve the messages from Kafka. Now after getting message or RDD now i use a map operation to process the messages independently on the executors. The one challenge I am facing is i need to read/write to a hive table from within the executors and for this i need access to SQLContext. But as far as i know SparkSession is available at driver side only and should not be used within the executors. Now without the spark session (in spark 2.1.1) i can't get hold of SQLContext. To summarize 
My driver codes looks something like:

```
if (inputDStream_obj.isSuccess) {
      val inputDStream = inputDStream_obj.get
      inputDStream.foreachRDD(rdd => {

        if (!rdd.isEmpty) {
           val rdd1 = rdd.map(idocMessage => SegmentLoader.processMessage(props, idocMessage.value(), true))
       }
}
```

So after this rdd.map the next code is executed on the executors and there I have something like:

```
val sqlContext = spark.sqlContext
 import sqlContext.implicits._
 spark.sql("USE " + databaseName)
 val result = Try(df.write.insertInto(tableName))
```

Passing sparksession or sqlcontext gives error when they are used on the executor:

- When I try to obtain the existing sparksession: `org.apache.spark.SparkException: A master URL must be set in your configuration`
- When I broadcast session variable:`User class threw exception: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 9, <server>, executor 2): java.lang.NullPointerException`
- When i pass sparksession object: `User class threw exception: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 9, <server>, executor 2): java.lang.NullPointerException`

Let me know if you can suggest how to query/update a hive table from within the executors.

Thanks,
Ritwick

Comment: You cannot use `SQLContext` this way. If you want to communicate with Hive within a task, use JDBC or other Spark independent Hive client.

Comment: Alright, i see challenge with this as well because using jdbc connector from within the task would be a problem for each incoming message (connection setup overhead). Though I can try setting up a connection pool for the executor but my intent is to identify the right way of doing it. If I have to store a raw message and process it as well then should i use driver to store the message (scalability challenges with huge message volume) in hive table and then use executors for rest of the processing. Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: You can use mapPartitions instead of map, but to be honest I am bit confused what is the goal here. Why not write a whole RDD?

Comment: I'm raising the same concerns as @zero323

Comment: Let me describe the use case in more detail: We are processing messages from source received via kafka. Then we process these messages as per usual rdd processing before storing this into kudu (on cloudera platform). But in order to process out of sequence message scenario wherein messages come in incorrect order we have to identify and replay the latest messages (for the same key). Kudu can be connected and used from within the executors and we used it as a raw message store (remember for out of sequence processing we need to retrieve the raw messages) but kudu has a cell limit of 64kb.

Comment: So essentially we had to use hive table and we need to store and read hive table after processing each message and it would be a scalable option only when we can do it from within the executors instead of the driver.